# Withdrawing 0x from 0x.org

Tags: 0x

I was successfully able to un-stake my 0x from the staking pool I had on https://0x.org/zrx/staking/pool

But I try to Withdraw my funds, nothing happens. I click on "Withdraw" which is next to my Available ZRX, but nothing happens when I click on it. It doesn't interact with my Metamask wallet or ask me to confirm anything. It's like clicking on any other word. Nothing happens.

I've tried disconnecting my wallet and reconnecting. I've tried different browsers (Chrome and Internet Explorer). I've tried restarting my computer.
Always the same result.

Please help!

Comment: Is something logging on the console of the browser when you click the button? Sometimes we dont see the error but if we look into the console we can see an error message

Comment: @D-Qba, back then when you opened the issue there was a problem with one of the gas fees oracle apis. This should be fixed now. Can you check now if withdrawing ZRX works for you? thanks